# Efficient way to compare multiple unordered large strings with duplicate characters

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I am looking for an efficient way in python to compare multiple large unordered strings with duplicate characters and return true or false depending on if they are the same.

Constraints:

- Characters are only alphabet
- String size can be thousands of characters

For example:

```
string_1 = "hjqzukcwwkpjzyvwjbdyfbjvjmqgimhgjiumaipiragpktuchkqqgfaycktkawjjytqytftdpfepnigtrxevbbwbyqfpfzawvdhdhyakfeyindxxdwkyccqhjgtcfpkanrauexvrijhmbwfbahcxdhzdzhfyjwivzrxmepbweygntikuburewahpynuxayaefczqmrrmfeafxfujqxfiwtgaddatuqdggcxcynvgvxijqmhaukvxmmzaykbtcbazwxyecivbyxyzvndpjncvzwkfwwpvyphadwdfejjiawqgryetzzxvzmjbtzctupimvcufcdpuajuaxactcrhgjjmifvdvvckbjgwhcxaqurdupzgkftvnqcbeuytipqanyaffmxmbaxvnitdytkgwvzarqmqaxzejbiqtaqxmnrikgzbvjddnqtexackvpwnwxwypmtxnfdjfujffqnrefgurnuumwhdfrfxfyqiaquwaeqrmkktaxzymnajazpwbpyaxqzckwrieaxkjcrkdizxekmtcgejprfzqjrbfgxjzfpwdknipfqjnmmfhnpexrxqyyztcmfjeakfzhnghinibdpyammgccxjcxnqeitmgfnqmkrwtwgzefbqmzhzgqymetedrwamebuadhhikcddfteugrynfdibimrrbxuwzhmfhxxixrumqxtkv"
string_2 = "indnrefgurnuumwhdfrfxfyqiaquwaeqrmkktaxzymnajazpwbpyaxqzckwrieaxkjcrkdizxekmtcgejprfzqjrbfgxjzfpwdknipfqjnmmfhnpexrxqyyztcmfjeakfzhnghinibdpyxxdwkyccqhjgtcfpkanrauexvrijhmbwfbahcxdhzdzhfyjwivzrxmepbweygntikuburewahpynuxayaefczqmrrmfeafxfujqxfiwtgaddatuqdggcxcynvgvxijqmhaukvxmmzaykbtcbazwxyecivbyxyzvndpjncvzwkfwwpvyphadwdfejjiawqgryetzzxvzmjbtzctupimvcufcdpuajuaxactcrhgjjmifvdvvckbjgwhcxaqurdupzgkftvnqcbeuytipqanyaffmxmbaxvnitdytkgwvzarqmqaxzehjqzukcwwkpjzyvwjbdyfbjvjmqgimhgjiumaipiragpktuchkqqgfaycktkawjjytqytftdpfepnigtrxevbbwbyqfpfzawvdhdhyakfeyjbiqtaqxmnrikgzbvjddnqtexackvpwnwxwypmtxnfdjfujffqammgccxjcxnqeitmgfnqmkrwtwgzefbqmzhzgqymetedrwamebuadhhikcddfteugrynfdibimrrbxuwzhmfhxxixrumqxtkv"

if sorted(string_1) == sorted(string_2):
    return True
```

This gets very slow as it is sorting the whole string before checking, I also cannot use sets as they are not taking into account a character occurrence. I would appreciate any input on ways to do this check.

Comment: Do they only contain letters a-z or also other characters?

Comment: How large are the strings?

Comment: @kellyBundy: They are only alphabetic and string size has no limit and gets to thousands of characters. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: As my benchmark shows, there are faster ways. But is yours really *"very slow"*? It still only takes a millisecond or so. Why did you call it *"very slow"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions and benchmark with string length 5000:

```
anagrams
  39.5 ±  0.1 μs  lifezbeautiful_and_Kelly
 300.5 ±  0.3 μs  Kelly
 456.0 ±  6.7 μs  Unmitigated
1244.4 ±  8.1 μs  chrisfang
1544.3 ±  8.1 μs  original

not anagrams
  13.9 ±  3.1 μs  Kelly
  39.6 ±  0.1 μs  lifezbeautiful_and_Kelly
 459.0 ±  8.9 μs  Unmitigated
1256.6 ± 12.9 μs  chrisfang
1549.4 ± 12.1 μs  original
```

Solution `Kelly` compares the length and the counts of 25 of the 26 letters:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc

def anagrams(s, t):
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False
    for c in abc[1:]:
        if s.count(c) != t.count(c):
            return False
    return True
```

Solution `lifezbeautiful_and_Kelly` uses NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def anagrams(s1, s2):
    def count(s):
        a = np.frombuffer(s.encode(), dtype=np.uint8)
        return np.bincount(a, minlength=123)
    return (count(s1) == count(s2)).all()
```

The `np.frombuffer(s.encode(), dtype=np.uint8)` is from @lifezbeautiful's deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75718787/12671057).

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVZNsqREEF7LKWrCBcWI2KAzMdEhKw03bnXV0UFUQ9JdNhRYVTj2e85J3MxG97p25QE8gKcxs6CA7n7PUFaQmfXl35dZ_Pxrf7GnTr1__8tg64_f_P3B7xXU7Gtomgs3MbPRNmD4yJo1oLiJ2IvcvXkFPRrsoBX7SjQGnLDuNCuZVEwcyl263S-miGOSshuU5aXDsvPXYvQk5iT4Rg8QBBRjI2t4OIAYrKyHphCqKqaw05iZbMIjy9GDWXkQLGeqT2rdtYehrkFzk4Aquwp4FLPKXnrIUT9IZd9Et3mi4iDVCCpi1kqFBTnaU55mn0brWPnkOI1YnvsosihKRNPwaMyi0_IolWi4sVqqY0Gxj28-gwnMdNpCNZs5yGtZNkF-q1pp5VGszZ9D_YKCovTXsDdCj1uetDS1UMfZekuoC7T79IQxhREtYJ1dx0iEyrQoT8IWrehRoaHsdEUSLcqrILx59l_Ms9m8OMPFoKUBy6-cJaTgUcR-8rrsTjcT90zE9WgLZRZA10hyc-XiiMDnmG2i9Yns7kT2bydoOm7cvMhvca7nZKnz3ahMKte7Z4q37hjpKK4t-1KWduc6i_zfI3SFAr5USE4VIoA5GJ-jh3Hpyav0vGonCXQ88BFL1zF7kyCg2USbpoHSyk4ZJtse6e7JOeqtbEFar9LQg7CjxlhhpbGynA-2IBRxtYIfAn8Al0bX-gOUjzcWppSyaLq3oEthAL9pl42WXQ9aWKrDaAvfj3KJYdmua2aPve6qobTemxra_kJIitIbVElc9fMfjzs3Xk9vvIxc_Oy6C4IPsSYaG2wVGINHoDyzt9KeWCvUhZkWtw2jJExAa6_BqvBQCHE4POATRgG11GTUUyw8D8Pku05ipabo0fbwEMZTcXPa_SKK_BZxBUzMCZdoA6gYRzFFPxOOl8GPPUaIcpf4brP3a3pmVU0RjNqrK0ODGRp3ko74E26LGwOu7aNBPjkJAqIFFfex3rLd_gb9nRsI4ofh9ZSHJeudZS9ZCq-dvXUcH_erg9vV-2i3zV7RkFowzl8olDhq0ZqQAQ4fSzeb_X5N5zp8JNpxi5fP6ySt37E_f2OPjoNO9pmT_fWHYWHg-uCQ0fOCHLNQdUhI_00B90hVy8kWV_NqJrEdR-AYxZQW9XtqUXnqZAmGI4tjds5fbTabeW-6pXvfsicT9X15uvNUBW_xP5xn986FPppxY97cX8EThLn6v5Dsc2zE9ZacmFLzl4TrLjl-nxte_U4aszopCoW7sygWthEF8a7n4yDwRrSHSmxnzJjm-wA6T_Ge-WTaau7cxJ5E9D0oZNPcs3rFMZcHFgcuuaPm1MGx056st4GN2mj8dZv-4Pyf3D8)):

```py
def Kelly(s, t):
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False
    for c in abc[1:]:
        if s.count(c) != t.count(c):
            return False
    return True

def lifezbeautiful_and_Kelly(s1, s2):
    def count(s):
        a = np.frombuffer(s.encode(), dtype=np.uint8)
        return np.bincount(a, minlength=123)
    return (count(s1) == count(s2)).all()

def original(string_1, string_2):
    return sorted(string_1) == sorted(string_2)

def Unmitigated(string_1, string_2):
    return Counter(string_1) == Counter(string_2)

def chrisfang(string_1: str, string_2: str):
    is_same = True
    str1_chat_map = record_character(string_1)
    str2_chat_map = record_character(string_2)
    str_keys = set(str1_chat_map.keys()) | set(str2_chat_map.keys())
    for k in str_keys:
        str1_chat_count = str1_chat_map.get(k, 0)
        str2_chat_count = str2_chat_map.get(k, 0)
        if str1_chat_count != str2_chat_count:
            is_same = False
    return is_same
def record_character(string: str):
    char_map: Dict[str, int] = dict()
    for i in string:
        count = char_map.get(i, 0)
        char_map[i] = count + 1
    return char_map

from collections import Counter
from timeit import repeat
from statistics import mean, stdev
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc
from operator import eq
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

funcs = original, Kelly, Unmitigated, chrisfang, lifezbeautiful_and_Kelly

# Correctness check with many small cases
a = list('aaabbzzzz')
for s2 in map(''.join, product('abz', repeat=len(a))):
    random.shuffle(a)
    s1 = ''.join(a)
    expect = funcs[0](s1, s2)
    for f in funcs[1:]:
        result = f(s1,s2)
        assert result == expect

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:25 if test == 'anagrams' else 100]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.1f} ± {stdev(ts):4.1f} μs '

for test in 'anagrams', 'not anagrams':
  print(test)

  for i in range(100):
    a = random.choices(abc, k=5000)
    string_1 = ''.join(a)
    if test == 'anagrams':
      random.shuffle(a)
    else:
      a = random.choices(abc, k=5000)
    string_2 = ''.join(a)
    args = string_1, string_2

    for f in funcs:
        if i < 10:
            assert f(*args) == (test == 'anagrams'), (test, f.__name__)
        t = min(repeat(lambda: f(*args), number=1)) / 1
        times[f].append(t)

  for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
  print()
```

Comment: Thanks @KellyBundy for getting back and including my name :). After you pointed out the mistake, I realised it was due to overflow of numpy multiplications over long sequences of primes. The only solution I could figure out was to use a multiplication using modulo 10ˆ9 + 7 but it has a small, a very very small probability of giving a wrong answer, so deleted the answer. The straightforward bincount is better I suppose. Plus its faster. Good that this answer was accepted. Seems we are a good team,

Comment: @lifezbeautiful Yes, or alternatively you could've used not the primes 2 to 109 but the primes 3 to 113, that would likewise make it harder to find an actual hash collision. But it remains a hash, so no chance of being fully correct. It could be done as a *first* test - if the hashes differ, you're done, and if they match, do a "full check". But in this case, where the full check is *faster*, that's no good. Also, it assumes that what happens for overflow is defined behavior, and I'm not sure it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.Counter`, which gets the frequency of each character in linear time.

```py
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(string_1) == Counter(string_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

can try this way

```
def compare_str(string_1: str, string_2: str):
    is_same = True
    str1_chat_map = record_character(string_1)
    str2_chat_map = record_character(string_2)
    str_keys = set(str1_chat_map.keys()) | set(str2_chat_map.keys())
    for k in str_keys:
        str1_chat_count = str1_chat_map.get(k, 0)
        str2_chat_count = str2_chat_map.get(k, 0)
        if str1_chat_count != str2_chat_count:
            is_same = False
    return is_same


def record_character(string: str):
    char_map: Dict[str, int] = dict()
    for i in string:
        count = char_map.get(i, 0)
        char_map[i] = count + 1
    return char_map
```